# Preferred CoffeeScript parenthesis style for function calls?

Tags: coding-style, standards, coffeescript

What is the preferred, accepted, best practice, etc. for parentheses in CoffeeScript method/function calls?

1. `foo(bar, baz).zap`?
2. `(foo bar, baz).zap`?

Always 1 or always 2? Or something else / it depends (please elaborate)

Answer (score 2):

The first style is more common. One reason is that in chains, only the first style can be used at every step of the chain:

```
foo(bar, baz).zap(yota).penumbra
```

However, consider that

```
new Foo.bar()
```

means "create a new instance of `Foo.bar`, whereas

```
(new Foo).bar()
```

means "create a new instance of `Foo` and call the `bar` method on that instance." By analogy to `new`, I prefer to use the second style when using a function like Node's `require`:

```
(require 'crypto').createHash 'sha1'
```